# Programming a delay in javafx script, is this possible?

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-6.9, javafx-1

Ok, so i have a problem with javafx, the netbeans 6.9.1 version that is (i know it's a bit old but i have to do this for a final assignement for school). So for the assignement i have to code a memory game (concentration). Now i want to program a delay so when i flip a card the function waits for like 1.5 seconds so that you can see the turned card. however, when i make a while loop to wait for the 1.5 second mark the program just freezes and the variable "time02" won't update. i then have to manually shut the program down via task manager because it just freezes. Here's a snippet of the code with the timeline and a small piece of the function. i also included the timeline for the clock which weirdly enough updates the variable "time01" just fine. I also put the code for delay in a comment.

```
clock = Timeline {
    repeatCount: Timeline.INDEFINITE
    keyFrames: KeyFrame {
        time: 0.1s
        action: function() {
            updateclock();
        }
    }
}
function updateclock() {
    time01 = time01 + 1;
    text2.content = "Tijd: {time01 / 10}";
}


/*
delay = Timeline {
    repeatCount: Timeline.INDEFINITE
    keyFrames: KeyFrame {
        time: 0.1s
        action: function() {
            updatedelay();
        }
    }
}

function updatedelay() {
    time02 = time02 + 0.1;
}
*/

function control() {
    if (counter == 2) {
        /*                                    
        while (time02 < 1.2) {
            delay.play();
        }
        delay.stop();
        time02 = 0;
        */
        ..............................
```

Any type of help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's treading issue. You can't wait for something which is calculated on the same thread.

You can put code which flips card back into the `Timeline` to make JavaFX care about threading instead of you.

```
backflip : Timeline {
   repeatCount: 1
   keyFrames: KeyFrame {
        time: 1.5s
        action: function() {
           // here is code which flips card back
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: @user2211347, wow, an answer accepted after 9 years! Thanks for the caring :)